# Cannot import GeoIP module in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm using Django 1.5.5.

settings.py:

```
GEOIP_PATH = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR,  'geoIP')
INSTALLED_APPS = (..,'django.contrib.gis',..)
```

views.py:

```
from django.contrib.gis import geoip
print geoip.HAS_GEOIP
```

the print gives `false`.

If I try one of the following I get a `ImportError: cannot import name GeoIP`

```
from django.contrib.gis.utils import GeoIP #this one is deprecated whatsoever
from django.contrib.gis.utils.geoip import GeoIP #this one is deprecated whatsoever
from django.contrib.gis.geoip import GeoIP
```

Generally it looks like `geoip` does not contain a `GeoIP` module.

Also if I open `python` in the terminal:

```
>>> from django.contrib.gis.geoip import GeoIP
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name GeoIP
```

---

Some more info, if I print:

```
from django.contrib.gis import geoip
print geoip
```

I get:

```
<module 'django.contrib.gis.geoip' from '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/geoip/__init__.pyc'>
```

Not sure if that can be a hint for someone to help me?

Comment: Do you have the GeoIP system-wide library installed? `django.contrib.gis.geoip` is just a wrapper around that, and you have to make sure it's installed.

Comment: @YuvalAdam Yes I had `INSTALLED_APPS = (..,'django.contrib.gis',..)` but with `django.contrib.gis.geoip ` does not make difference. I should have it under `INSTALLED_APPS` right?

Comment: Not installed in Django (which is irrelevant). Installed **system-wide**. Try `brew install geoip` is you use homebrew.

Comment: What do you get if you do `from django.contrib.gis.geoip.base import GeoIP`?

Comment: Alpine linux, or Docker or Python or some combination appears to have a bug that causes this import error
https://github.com/docker-library/python/issues/111
https://bugs.alpinelinux.org/issues/4512
https://bugs.python.org/issue21622
I was able to work around it by `pip install GeoIP` but I don't understand why that worked.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It looks like you don't have GeoIP installed system-wide. `django.contrib.gis.geoip` is just a wrapper around the GeoIP library, and it must be installed regardless.

On OS X, if you use homebrew, just run `brew install geoip`. If not, you need to make sure the GeoIP lib is installed, and that you have `libGeoIP.dylib` located wherever your system keeps its libraries.

Comment: Thanks. I also used `pip install geoip` on my server.

Comment: In django 1.7 I used ```from django.contrib.gis.geoip import GeoIP```

Comment: Please use geopi2 as geoip has since been deprecated