# ImportError: cannot import name 'GeoIP'

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, geoip

I have installed GeoIP C library with `brew install geoip` and it was successfully. I also installed it through `pip install geoip` but when trying to import GeoIP from Django I get the following error:

```
>>> from django.contrib.gis.geoip import GeoIP
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'GeoIP'
```

I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20033552/cannot-import-geoip-module-in-django) question but it didn't answer my question though I know GeoIP library is installed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot import GeoIP module in Django](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20033552/cannot-import-geoip-module-in-django)

Comment: @RandomDavis No, I have looked at that one and I have the library installed. So that doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, need to do:

```
brew install geoip
```

Then, check where Homebrew will put the GeoIP files. For example, output on my end is:

```
==> Pouring geoip-1.6.12.mojave.bottle.1.tar.gz
  /usr/local/Cellar/geoip/1.6.12: 18 files, 553.0KB
```

So, set this in local settings so that Django's GeoIP could locate it:

```
GEOIP_PATH = '/usr/local/Cellar/geoip/1.6.12/'
```

as per https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/geoip2/#std:setting-GEOIP_PATH. After that, the import error is gone.